# Inheriting from beamer

Tags: best-practices, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to write (my first) document class which will be an extension of `beamer`. In particular I want this class to produce the slides that I like.

One of the things that I want is to have a macro `\logosmall` which will tell the class where to find the (small) logo which will be used. Here is what I tried:

In the class:

```
\let\@logosmall\relax
\def\logosmall#1{\def\@logosmall{#1}}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.8cm]{university-logo}{\@logosmall}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}
```

and in the document itself:

```
\logosmall{logos/path_to_logo}
```

The error I get is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.25 ...eight=0.8cm]{university-logo}{\@logosmall}
```

What am I doing wrong? I guess almost everything - but as I said this is my very first attempt!

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the fact that you are declaring the image before `\@logosmall` has been set.  Surely the `\pgfdeclareimage` should only occur after `\logosmall` has been called.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Probably you're right, but how can I fix it? How can I place `\pdfdeclareimage` inside the class? What is the best practice here?

Comment: First thing I would do is investigate whether or not you really want to use pgf's image handling instead of `\includegraphics`.  If so, you have to move the `\pgfdeclareimage` somewhere between `\logosmall` and the first use of `\logo`.  One place would be in the definition of `\logosmall` itself.  Another might be in `\AtBeginDocument` if you can guarantee that `\logosmall` is preamble-only.  A third possibility would be in the call to `\logo` itself: on the *first* invocation call the `\pgfdeclareimage` function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually the line

```
\let\@logosmall\relax
```

as we can see if we make minimal example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\let\@logosmall\relax
\def\logosmall#1{\def\@logosmall{#1}}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.8cm]{university-logo}{\@logosmall}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

and insert `\tracingall` just before `\pgfdeclareimage`:

```
\pgfutil@IfFileExists #1#2#3->\openin \pgfutil@inputcheck =#1 \ifeof \pgfutil@i
nputcheck #3\relax \else #2\relax \fi \closein \pgfutil@inputcheck 
#1<-\@logosmall .pdf
#2<-\xdef \pgf@filename {\@logosmall .pdf}
#3<-\def \pgf@mightbeempty {.jpg:.jpeg:.png::}\ifx \pgf@mightbeempty \pgfutil@e
mpty \else \pgf@findfile .jpg:.jpeg:.png::+{\@logosmall }\fi 
{\openin}
{\relax}
{the character .}
\everypar->\@nodocument
```

The `\openin` primitive is looking for a file name, but the `\relax` terminates name scanning meaning it looks for an entirely empty file name, leaving the `.pdf` part 'hanging' and firing the error from LaTeX.

A simple fix is to do

```
\newcommand*{\@logosmall}{}
```

as this is now an empty-but-expandable definition. That will then search for a file `.pdf`, which probably won't exist but at least won't fire an error. Of course, that still won't actually work correctly as the image declaration has already happened.

As you note in your own answer, the correct approach is to do things a bit differently. I don't see why you are using `\pgfdeclareimage` here, as I'd go for using `\includegraphics`. You could do that with a stored file name:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@logosmall}{}
\newcommand*{\logosmall}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@logosmall}{#1}}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{\@logosmall}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

or  without:

```
\newcommand*{\logosmall}[1]{%
  \logo{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{#1}}%
}
```

(From the question the need to store is not entirely clear.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, and seems to work:

In the class I put the following (instead of what you can find in the OP):

```
\newcommand*{\logosmall}[1]{%
  \pgfdeclareimage[height=0.8cm]{university-logo}{#1}
}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}
```

Then, in the document's preamble I have `\logosmall{path/to/logo}`.

This seems to work as I expected, however, I cannot tell how robust it is? Is this a good way to tackle the issue.